# return statement not exiting for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

I want to hover over createJS labels and show english translation output only for the chinese label (Ex: "Wan" would show "Bowl") that I hover over.

1) So I add all my labels on create to an array

2) Then loop through all labels in `hitTest()` and add mouseover/mouseout handler to them

3) then `handleMouseEvent()` will call toggle english label on or off depending on hover

4) then `toggleItemLabel()` loops through all createJS containers containing that label... if the hovered Chinese word matches the label that belongs to the container, then it will set that second english label's input, and show it.

This works fine, except the `toggleItemLabel()` seems to continue looping through all labels in `allMyLabels[]` even after it has found a match and returned.

As you can see from the output, it's showing 4 outputs... which means it's not returning/exiting the loop when it finds a match.

Why is this?

Output:

```
Lee Xian Sheng, Lee Xian Sheng 
Lee Xian Sheng, Lee Xian Sheng 
Lee Xian Sheng, Lee Xian Sheng 
Lee Xian Sheng, Lee Xian Sheng
```

[image]

```
function hitTest() {
    for (var i = 0 ; i < allMyLabels.length; ++i) {
        allMyLabels[i].on("mouseover", handleMouseEvent);
        allMyLabels[i].on("mouseout", handleMouseEvent);
    }
}

function handleMouseEvent(evt) {
    for (var i = 0 ; i < allMyLabels.length; ++i) {
        if (evt.type === "mouseover") { 
            toggleItemLabel(allMyLabels[i].text, false);        
        }
        else {
            toggleItemLabel(allMyLabels[i].text, true);
        }
    }
}

function toggleItemLabel(word, hide) {

    for (var i = 0; i < All_Items_Array.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < All_Items_Array[i].children.length; j++) {
            log(word + ", " + All_Items_Array[i].children[j].children[1].text);
            if (word === All_Items_Array[i].children[j].children[1].text) {
                if (hide) {
                    return All_Items_Array[i].children[j].children[2].text = "";
                }
                else {
                    return All_Items_Array[i].children[j].children[2].text = All_Items_Array[i].children[j].name;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    stage.update();
}
```

---

EDIT: to give some insight as to what is in All_Items_Array:

When a new item is created:

```
function createNewItem(itemObj) {
    if (itemObj.name != "undefined") {
        if (!checkIfExists(itemObj.name) || itemObj.quest_name == null) {       
            container = new createjs.Container();
            bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(itemObj.path);
            container.x = itemObj.x;
            container.y = itemObj.y;
            container.name = itemObj.name;

            container.taskNum = 0;

            cn_label = new createjs.Text(itemObj.cn_name, "14px Arial", "white");   
            cn_label.y = -45;

            en_label = new createjs.Text("", "14px Arial", "black");    
            en_label.y = -25;           

            //loop through all labels, check hittest for each
            allMyLabels.push(cn_label);

            container.addChild(bitmap, cn_label, en_label);

            container.cn = itemObj.cn_name;

            if (itemObj.itemType === "newItem") {
                container.count = 0;
                ContainerOfItems.addChild(container);
            }
            else {
                container.questName = itemObj.quest_name;
                ContainerOfPeople.addChild(container)
            }       
        }
        else {
            log(itemObj.quest_name + " already added...");
        }
    }
    hitTest(); //add mouse listeners to newly added labels
    stage.update();
}
```

And `All_Items_Array.push(ContainerOfPeople, ContainerOfItems);`

---

**EDIT 2**: tried break statements in the loop instead of returns:

Now when I hover over label, it returns english labels for all chinese labels:

[image]

The first `console.log()` outputs all items in array, regardless if `word===label text` or not. This is wrong. Hovering over `wan` should only return when `wan === wan`:

```
wǎn , Lee Xian Sheng 
wǎn , fàn 
wǎn , shūcài 
wǎn , wǎn  
text: bowl, result: bowl
```

Updated `toggleItemLabel()` code:

```
function toggleItemLabel(word, hide) {
    var result = "", label = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < All_Items_Array.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < All_Items_Array[i].children.length; j++) {
            log(word + ", " + All_Items_Array[i].children[j].children[1].text);
            if (word === All_Items_Array[i].children[j].children[1].text) {
                label = All_Items_Array[i].children[j].children[2];
                if (hide) {
                    result = "";
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    result = All_Items_Array[i].children[j].name;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    label.text = result;
    log("text: " + label.text + ", result: " +  result);
    return label;
}
```

Comment: Returning during a loop like that is bad practice. You should save those results to a variable and simply **break** your loops, then return the variable at the end of the function.

Comment: Agree with @scrowler , it also increases readability and reduces debugging efforts.

Comment: @scrowler I've tried it with the breaks and using a variable to return. It's not working. I've added the updated code in "EDIT 2" above.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite that to look more like

```
function hitTest() {
    $(allMyLabels).on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
        var word = $(this).text, 
            hide = e.type == 'mouseenter';

        $.each(All_Items_Array, function(_, arr) {
            $.each(arr.children, function(_, child) {
                var w = child.children[1].text;
                log(word + ", " + w);
                if (word == w) {
                    child.children[1].text = hide ? child.name : '';
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks adeneo, much more elegant of a solution. It doesn't work, however. in `log(word + ", " + w)`, word gives `function (a){return f.access(this,function(a){return a===b?f.text(this):this.empty().append((this[0]&&this[0].ownerDocument||c).createTextNode(a))},null,a,arguments.length)}`

Comment: @Growler - I have no idea what these `children` and `text` properties are ? It seems you have an array with some objects etc. and only you know what's in that array? Of course, there are jQuery methods called `children()` and `text()` as well, but I assumed you where not trying to use those as that would require actual jQuery objects and calling the functions, but the logged result you're getting does seem like you're really trying to use jQuery's `text()`, but who knows !

Comment: Okay I've added some context above. Does that help? Essentially, they are createJS objects: `All_Items_Array[i].children[j].children[1].text` is: All_Items_Array[i] =  ContainerOfItems or  ContainerOfPeople. Then All_Items_Array[i].children[j] = new container created within `createNewItem()` and added to parent `ContainerOfPeople`. Finally, `All_Items_Array[i].children[j].children[1]` is the second child (createJS text object) added to container. I'm trying to access this label's `text` attr.

Comment: So I don't think I can use $(allMyLabels) as the labels are createJS text objects, and not DOM objects.